# Facebook 'secret' value, or Authenticating an app after facebook login / registration

Tags: apache-flex, security, spring, facebook

I have an existing Spring application which I wish to also allow users to register / sign in through facebook.

The facebook sign-in is working fine, and is currently executed from the client using the Actionscript-Facebook API ( which is essentially a wrapper for the Facebook JS API).

However I'm unsure as to what is an appropriate approach for me to take in using the client-side authenticated session to authenticate against my own app server / session (ie., the Spring session).

In my own application, the user registers/authenticates with an email address & password.

My first thoughts in a facebook authenticated solution is to use the facebook `email` and `secret` values returned from the `login` call.  These would be stored in my database when the user performs registration via facebook, (or specifically, a hash of `secret`) and using these to authenticate during login in the same manner as a regular login.

However, I'm unsure of what the `secret` value actually is, and whether it's a appropriate to use in this scenario.  (The [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login) seems unclear in what the return values of the login call actually mean)

- Is this value bound to the user, or the session?
- Does this value change, should the user change their password on Facebook?
- Is this an appropriate value to store a hash of?

Finally, is there a more appropriate way of achieving this task?